# How to write Test for sourceSets block in Gradle plugin

Tags: java, gradle, groovy, gradle-plugin

Recently, I was working on a project which was using many gradle groovy plugins and I had introduced a piece of block to, add some static files in sourceSets. Now how do I write the test for the sourceSets block?
The block I added in sourceSets is

```
 project.sourceSets {
            test {
                resources {
                    srcDir project.files("${project.projectDir}/some-folder")
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a way to write the test this scenario, place your resources in 
some folder named and tempFile is the resource for test. And the Test for the same: **TestPluginSpec.groovy**

```
 @Rule
    TemporaryFolder testProjectDir = new TemporaryFolder()
    File tempFile
    tempFile = testProjectDir.newFile('tempFile')
    buildFile = testProjectDir.newFile('build.gradle')

    buildFile << """
             plugins {
                id 'java'
               }
   """
def "should add test Resources into build/resources/test"(){
        when:
        def result = GradleRunner.create().withProjectDir(testProjectDir.root).withPluginClasspath().withArguments('processTestResources').withDebug(true).build()
        then:
        result.task(":processTestResources").outcome == TaskOutcome.SUCCESS
        and:
        Files.exists(Paths.get("${testProjectDir.root.path}/build/resources/test/tempFile"))
    }
```